# Localized resx files as sub items in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, resx, solution-explorer

We have a large number of C# projects in a visual studio solution. For a lot of these we have a resource file called 'TextResources.resx'. These have been translated in the past creating several related resx files for example 'TextResources.fr.resx'. For these older projects these translated resx files are showing as sub items of the default english TextResources.resx however for several new projects the translated items are appearing as separate (same tree level) items.

Hopefully this diagram will explain:

Old Projects:

```
- TextResources.resx
     - TextResources.fr.resx 
     - TextResources.de.resx
```

New Projects:

```
- TextResources.fr.resx 
- TextResources.de.resx 
- TextResources.resx
```

This not only looks odd but is a little confusing with so many projects. Anyone know why its grouping some translated resx files but not others?

Comment: For the record - I have never discovered an answer for this question. Sometimes deleting the resx and adding new helped but not always. I guess this will remain a mystery...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and found no answer either.

I ended up editing the project (.csproj) file by hand.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\TextResources.de.resx">
  <DependentUpon>TextResources.resx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Add the

```
<DependentUpon></DependentUpon>
```

tag and type out the name of the "parent" resource file without leading folders.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the custom file nesting feature in VS2019 here's an example: -

https://mitch.codes/tip-visual-studio-custom-file-nesting/

Once you have the [customised] "xx.filenesting.json" file open for editing, just add an entry for ".resx" in the path segments section: -

look in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NestingProfiles

```
      "pathSegment": {
        "add": {
          ".*": [
            ".js",
            ".css",
            ".html",
            ".htm",
            ".less",
            ".scss",
            ".coffee",
            ".iced",
            ".config",
            ".cs",
            ".vb",
            ".json",
            ".resx"          <-----
          ]
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

> This solution for **Visual Studio 2019**

```
  <!-- Main Resource file -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Path\TextResources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>TextResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

 <!-- Resource Designer class -->    
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Path\TextResources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>TextResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Nested Resources files -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Path\TextResources.en.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Path\TextResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Path\TextResources.de.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Path\TextResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Path\TextResources.ar.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Path\TextResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```