# Is there a DependentUpon option in a .net core app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

In my `.net core` application, I would like to have my partial files put under a given file like it was with a .net framework application using the tag `DependentUpon` in the `csproj`.

As shown in a picture, I would like all `Program.*.cs` files to be under `Program.cs`.

[image]

However, in the `.csproj` file, I do not see the file listed:

[image]

Is there a way to do that in a `.net core` app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you just put an entry in an `ItemGroup` to update the implicit `Compile` elements from globbing. I'd personally use a separate `ItemGroup` element for this, away from your dependencies:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Program.*.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Program.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is the folder structure as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208978/7547389).  If the files are located in a folder, then you reference the parent **without** the folder, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Models\Person.*.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Person.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```